# The system cannot infer the transport information from the /favicon.ico URL using WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2-esb

I am getting this strange error with favicon.ico, how to solve it?

I do not have and I do not need to send a favicon.

**Proxy:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target endpoint="testEnd">
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ContentType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**Log:**

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,187] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Start : Log mediator {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,188]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /favicon.ico, MessageID: urn:uuid:aac40b4f-c896-4c17-84be-2809bd8c696d, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,188] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  End : Log mediator {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,188] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} -  Start : Send mediator {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,188] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator} -  Sending request message using implicit message properties..
Sending To: /favicon.ico
SOAPAction: null {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,189] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Sending [add = false] [sec = false] [rm = false] [to=Address: /favicon.ico] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,189] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient} -  Message [Original Request Message ID : urn:uuid:aac40b4f-c896-4c17-84be-2809bd8c696d] [New Cloned Request Message ID : urn:uuid:0a662d4e-a3c4-4fbe-b433-38336144aa08] {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,189] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils} -  The system cannot infer the transport information from the /favicon.ico URL. {org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-08-17 12:36:08,190] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /favicon.ico URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.InMediator.mediate(InMediator.java:61)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:228)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How do you call this proxy service "test" in the ESB, what do send to it ?

Comment: I call it using localhost:8280/services/test and it gets data from DSS (enpoint is localhost:9764/services/Test_DataService/test)

Comment: I think that your browser send a request to favicon.ico to the ESB, use "try this service" in the proxy config inside ESB Web console...

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, when i use `curl http://localhost:8280/services/test` there is no error with flavicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

I believe this favorite icon error in the log has been fixed in newer versions of products from WSO2. Here's an example from Micro Integrator server 4.1.0 running inside of Integration Studio Editor.

**Proxy**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="test" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom" separator=",">
                <property name="DEBUG" value="Hello World"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

**Log**

```
[2022-09-27 20:42:28,479]  INFO {EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Logging configuration changed. (Event Admin service unavailable - no notification sent).
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,055]  INFO {ProxyService} - {proxy:test} Building Axis service for Proxy service : test
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,058]  INFO {ProxyService} - {proxy:test} Adding service test to the Axis2 configuration
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,059]  INFO {ProxyService} - {proxy:test} Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : test
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,059]  INFO {ProxyServiceDeployer} - ProxyService named 'test' has been deployed from file : /Applications/IntegrationStudio.app/Contents/Eclipse/runtime/microesb/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1664329353008TestCompositeApplication_1.0.0.car/test_1.0.0/test-1.0.0.xml
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,065]  INFO {CappDeployer} - Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : favicondemoCompositeExporter_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT{super-tenant}
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,066]  INFO {AppDeployerServiceComponent} - Dashboard is configured. Initiating heartbeat component.
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,123]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8290
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,128]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0.0.0.0:8253
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,130]  INFO {StartupFinalizer} - WSO2 Micro Integrator started in 11.37 seconds
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,202]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9201
[2022-09-27 20:42:33,246]  INFO {PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
[2022-09-27 20:42:35,903]  INFO {AuthenticationHandlerAdapter} - User admin logged in successfully
[2022-09-27 20:43:10,855]  INFO {LogMediator} - {proxy:test} DEBUG = Hello World
[2022-09-27 20:52:42,486]  INFO {LogMediator} - {proxy:test} DEBUG = Hello World
```

As you can see there was no call for the favorite icon when I made this call from Safari and Chrome: http://localhost:8290/services/test

I believe the best answer to this very old question is to update to the latest version of API Manager/Micro Integrator Server.